# Parameter Value is being treated as a data type - PL/pgSQL

Tags: function, plpgsql

I am new to using PL/pgSQL. I've been a SQL Server Developer for the past 3 years. I'm trying to write a function using Dynamic SQL to pass in a table name and then pass a value and that table name back out.

I'm still trying to figure how how to write stored procs and functions in PostgreSQL, but I can't find any documentation how to do something like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exc_tables (tname VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE (module_id bigint, tablename varchar) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT DISTINCT module_id, '||CAST(tname AS varchar)||' as tablename FROM ' || tname || ' WHERE module_ID <> 6');

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
  Detail: Returned type dt_conn_type does not match expected type character varying in column 2.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function exc_tables(character varying) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to put the `cast()` into the query.

```
...
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT DISTINCT module_id, CAST('''||tname||''' AS varchar) as tablename FROM ' || tname || ' WHERE module_ID <> 6');
...
```

But since it already is a `varchar` the cast is useless and you could just go with:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT DISTINCT module_id, '''||tname||''' as tablename FROM ' || tname || ' WHERE module_ID <> 6');
```

But you need to make sure to enclose it in single quotes in the query to make it a string literal as otherwise it means the whole record (which has the type of whatever `tname` is then, so not a `varchar`).

And BTW, using `format()` with only a placeholderless format string and no replacement arguments is also pretty useless.